# "unreflected", is it correct?

Tags: british-english, single-word-requests

It seems for me that "unreflected" is not an English word.
What is a good alternative for it that means "not reflected"?
I need to use it in this context: "We use ... that compensates the unreflected beams to .....".

Comment: Well, there is no verb _to unreflect_, which may be what you mean; but _unreflected_ is an adjective formed by negating the adjective _reflected_.

Comment: Aside (not an answer).  I would have chucked unreflected for absorbed.

Comment: Not necessarily absorbed.  Could be refracted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than going by what 'seems for' you, I suggest using a dictionary

> unreflected (ˌʌnrɪˈflɛktɪd  )
>
> ►Definitions
>
> adjective
>
> 1.foll by on or upon not considered
>
> 2. (of light, particles, etc, incident on a surface) not reflected; absorbed or transmitted
>
> [Collins Dictionary](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/unreflected)

Comment: Thank you. I checked Google Translate and it was not there.

Comment: It depends what language you checked, e.g. https://translate.google.co.uk/#auto/es/unreflected

Answer (score 1):

I checked with my physicist spouse, who says, "I distinguish between *reflected* beams and *direct* beams."

I proposed a possible sentence:

> We use such-and-so method to compensate for the direct (OR forward-scattered) beam.

My spouse then laughed and said, "For my stuff, I just put a beam-stop there."

We need more context.